# counting number of times items appear in an array..and order them

Tags: perl

```
my @array=qw(1 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4);    
my %counts=();
map {$counts{$_}++} @array;
print Dumper(%counts);
```

produces:

```
$VAR1 = '4';
$VAR2 = 2;
$VAR3 = '1';
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = '3';
$VAR6 = 5;
$VAR7 = '2';
$VAR8 = 6;
```

How can I order the output in descending order so that the most frequently-appearing is first? (The output does not necessarily have to be a hash):

```
$VAR1 = '2';
$VAR2 = 6;
$VAR3 = '3';
$VAR4 = 5;
$VAR5 = '4';
$VAR6 = 2;
$VAR7 = '1';
$VAR8 = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide an appropriate function to `sort`:

```
map {$counts{$_}++} @array;
foreach my $key (sort { $counts{$b} <=> $counts{$a} } keys %counts) {
    print "$key => count is $counts{$key}\n";
}
```